# Mount network drive based on network

Tags: networking, mount, network-shares

We are using a Synology system to store and share files in our office. Usually 8 people are working there with their home computer (50% OSX and 50% Windows users). Each time I mount a network drive at home and use the computer in our office I need to mount the correct drive manually. I'd like to have that network drives at work mount automatically if my computer is connected to the network in our office and vice versa.

Could you please give me an advice how to do that?